# Audio Output being piped through audio input in Skype

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype

As stated in the title, my audio output seems to be piped into my audio input, and I'd like to change this. (For example, if I am talking to someone on Skype, not only is what they say being piped back to input, but also is any other sound that I may have in the background).

Pavucontrol shows that my output device isn't doing anything, yet when I mute it output stops. It does, however, show that the input device is doing what I would have expected the output to be doing. Muting the input does not stop the output.

Has anyone seen this before, or have any ideas? I'm not sure what other information would be helpful, but I'm happy to provide more to anyone who knows what to look for.

Output of `amxer -c1 scontents`:

`Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono: Playback 66 [89%] [-8.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-74.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-74.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 253 [99%] [-0.40dB]
  Front Right: Playback 253 [99%] [-0.40dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 2 [67%] [24.00dB]
  Front Right: 2 [67%] [24.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 7
  Mono: Playback 3 [43%] [-16.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 80 [100%] [6.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]`

Comment: Show the output of `amixer scontents`.

Comment: `Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0

  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  
Playback channels: Mono

  Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1

  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined

  Playback channels: Mono

  Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2

  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined

  Playback channels: Mono

  Mono: Playback [on]`

Comment: Oops, that is the HDMI output. Please show the output of `amixer -c1 scontents`, and put it into the question.

Comment: Alright, that's done.

Comment: Try reducing the "(Internal) Mic Boost" controls.